# Error c: out of memory. Segmentation fault with Pandas on machine with 512GB of RAM

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I am processing two datasets with read_csv function from Pandas (0.17.1), but when the datasets are 4.7GB and 3.5GB, I get:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
/var/spool/gridscheduler/execd/node018/job_scripts/22813: line 10: 99644 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When the datasets are of 3.3GB and 2.5GB everything works fine. I suspected this was because of the stack size but when checking with `ulimit -a`, the following information is displayed:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) 4294967296
pending signals                 (-i) 2062226
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2062226
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

pd.show_versions() displays:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.12.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_GB.UTF-8

pandas: 0.17.1
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 8.1.2
setuptools: 23.0.0
Cython: 0.23.4
numpy: 1.11.1
scipy: 0.17.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
IPython: 4.0.3
sphinx: 1.3.5
patsy: 0.4.0
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.7
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.4.6
matplotlib: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 2.3.2
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.8.4
lxml: 3.5.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: None
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.11
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
Jinja2: None
```

The machine has 512GB of RAM and is using CentOS. Why I am getting this error with the ingestion of ~8GB?

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a 32-bit version of something.

Comment: It's completely ok to downvote, I just would like to know why. Feedback is always very useful! If I ask is because I don't know after being searching for answers, and It does not make sense to me. If I am missing a place in which I should have looked to find the answer, it helps to let me know. Help and contributions is much better than downvotes without feedback.

Comment: @user2357112 If it was the 32-bit version issue, shouldn't I get error with 5.8GB too?

Comment: can you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39358895/edit) an output of `pd.show_versions()`? Did you try to read your CSV in chunks?

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for the help! :) I updated the post, and yes, with chunks it works, but more than how to read the CSV I would like to understand why given such hig RAM, I get an out of memory error with 8GB, which I don't quite understand the reason yet.

Comment: @SparkGeek, there was a bug in old pandas versions (<=0.14.1) causing this error. As a workaround people used `engine='python'` parameter - give it a try with your data.